# Creating slope map from DEM of Lunar South Pole

Tags: dem, slope

I've managed to create slope maps from other DEM's without much issue, but this DEM seems to have trouble and only does the very top section, with the rest being an error.

I am very much a beginner in QGIS.

I get the following error:

> ERROR 1: C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx Internship/Models/SouthPoleRegion/LRO_LOLA_DEM_SPole75_30m.tif:Using code not yet in table ERROR 1: TIFFReadEncodedStrip() failed. ERROR 1: C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx Internship/Models/SouthPoleRegion/LRO_LOLA_DEM_SPole75_30m.tif, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 5393: TIFFReadEncodedStrip() failed.

My Image is only partially transformed into a slope as shown on this image:

[image]

Comment: Hi @rudift, could you copy/paste the code of the error in your question, it will make it easier to understand for other people

Comment: @PierrickRambaud for sure:

ERROR 1: C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx Internship/Models/SouthPoleRegion/LRO_LOLA_DEM_SPole75_30m.tif:Using code not yet in table 
ERROR 1: TIFFReadEncodedStrip() failed.
ERROR 1: C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx Internship/Models/SouthPoleRegion/LRO_LOLA_DEM_SPole75_30m.tif, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 5393: TIFFReadEncodedStrip() failed.